# iOS Swift | Core data fetch by specific value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fetch

I have this model for Core data:

```
class Posts: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var title: String?
@NSManaged var author: String?
@NSManaged var url: String?
@NSManaged var isFavorite: NSNumber?
}
```

I want to add favorites functionality to my app.

How can I fetch entities that has attribute `isFavorite == true`? I have managed to fetch all the data so far, but I need the ones that has specific isFavorite value.

Comment: You can fetch all data and check whether isFavorite is true.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but when I try to display that filtered data I really don't know how to count isFavorite == true entities inside numberOfItemsInSection.. I'm filtering the data, but I'm count all the data. That leaves me with bunch of blank cells.

Comment: You can add a second array and use that to setup the contents.

Comment: I think I solved the problem, by inserting those elements in a different array :) Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Fetching only the objects with favorite = true is quite easy, you just have to set a predicate with it. Something like this should give you some lights:

```
    class func fetchFavourites(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext)->[Posts]{

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Posts")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isFavorite = \(NSNumber(bool:true))")

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {

        let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Posts]
        return results

    } catch let error as NSError {

    }

    return []
}
```

Comment: Too complicated: `isFavorite == TRUE` since it's declared as boolean in Core Data